# specifying the length of string in Yii migration

Tags: php, migration, yii

I wish to create a migration whose up method will execute the create_table function.

For example :

```
class m101129_185401_create_news_table extends CDbMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $this->createTable('tbl_news', array(
            'id' => 'pk',
            'title' => 'string NOT NULL',
            'content' => 'text',
        ));
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $this->dropTable('tbl_news');
    }
}
```

How do I specify the length of a field  in the migration ? Eg. What would I write if I have to specify that length of the title field should be 100 .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey! I believe this was an addition they did last year. I havent tried it, but doesn't this work?

```
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('tbl_news', array(
        'id' => 'pk',
        'title' => 'varchar(20) NOT NULL',
        'content' => 'text',
    ));
}
```

Also, in [this](https://github.com/pieterclaerhout/yii-dbmigrations/commit/5aa8b3eec6382988072f024bcb1f4d04b429c1c8) site you'll find information which can be helpful, as well as [here](https://github.com/pieterclaerhout/yii-dbmigrations). Good luck with this!

Comment: The problem of this solution is that it is not cross-DB compatible. "varchar(20)" is not a valid field type for example in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `SchemaBuilderTrait::string()` with a length parameter.

It has been 10 years since the original answer was posted, and the available ways to create that migration have improved.

The current way to do what the OP asked for, in a cross-DB compatible way, now would be:

```php
public function safeUp()
{
    $this->createTable(
        'tbl_news',
        [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'title' => $this->string(100)->notNull(),
            'content' => $this->text(),
        ]
    );
}
```